# Leaflet.Draw - GeoJSON to KML

Tags: leaflet, geojson, convert, kml, leaflet-draw

I have made a map using the Leaflet Draw plugin which allows the user to download their drawn items. These drawnItems are exported as GeoJSON using the following code from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/d30c44b081be31aea483):

```
document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
// Extract GeoJSON from featureGroup
var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();

// Stringify the GeoJSON
var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + 
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

// Create export
document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);      
document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download','data.geojson');
}
```

This works perfectly, but it would be even more ideal if the GeoJSON was converted to .kml before being exported. I am aware of the [toKml plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/tokml) but I am struggling to get it to work (I am still quite new to all of this). Where would I add:

```
var kml = tokml(geojsonObject);
```

And I am sure I would have to edit the //create export part of the GeoJSON code

Comment: Cross posted on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149464/leaflet-draw-geojson-to-kml The answer there sounds reasonable. It seems unfair looking for help somewhere else without even providing some feedback to the person who tried to help you already.

Comment: Feedback provided on Stackoverflow. The answer was 99% correct, I just had to make one small change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();
var kml = tokml(data);

var convertedData = 'application/xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
encodeURIComponent(kml);

// if you want to use the official MIME type for KML
// var convertedData = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;charset=utf-8,'+ 
// encodeURIComponent(kml);

document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData); 
document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download', 'data.kml');
```